# Cannot read text files outside the asset folder with Angular Android

Tags: angular, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have the following file 'test.txt'

Currently it its stored like so:
assets/test.txt

and I fetch the file like so:

```
    fetch('./assets/test.txt').then(res => res.text())
      .then(text => {
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Works');
            return;
          }, (e) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e.err));
          });
      });
```

I want to move this text file to another directory ie
app/services/databaseService/test.txt

The fetch from above is inside a file that is located in databaserService/ so under the same directory

When fetching from this new location:
fetch('./test.txt').then(res => res.text())

or
fetch('./app/services/databaseServices/test.txt').then(res => res.text())

both fail and the console log in android studio is

```
Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/app/services/databaseServices/test.txt
```

so it only works if the txt is in the assets folder.

How can I make it so the file can be read from the new location.

Note this is a Ionic Angular app build for both Android and iOS.

Thanks

[Image of file stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D6v0.png)

Comment: Random files outside of the assets folder do not get included in builds or the final distribution artifacts. If you want to read files like this, include it in the assets folder. That's all there is to it.

Comment: This is mobile development, you're not supposed to store files in random places. Check this https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you could try to import it. but this file won't be dynamic. you would have to provide this file during build time.

```
import str from 'raw-loader!./test.txt';
```